# How can I track duration of an app running in Android

Tags: android

I am fairly new to android and I am suppose to create an app that can monitor the users App Usage however I am not sure where I should start to search for . What classes can I use to monitor the user time spent on app and most frequently used.

Comment: you should create a thread which Log something each second, with a `wait(1000)`(1 second) for example

Comment: there are so many party lib available to track user spent time in your application like google analytic , flurry , mixpanle... so read this lib

Comment: you can create one service this service will calculates time and stored.one important thing add to boot completion in manifest file.`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some analytics free 3rd party service, such as [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) or [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics).

Answer (score 0):

The [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) has a set of API calls to see what applications are running. Be wary that the `getRecentTasks(int, int)` function is deprecated/nerfed since API 21.